# Repeat specific row or column of Python numpy 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a simple 2D numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

>>> arr = np.array([[4, 8, 5, 9], [3, 5, 9, 1], [2, 4, 5, 3]], np.int8)
array([[4 8 5 9]
       [3 5 9 1]
       [2 4 5 3]])
```

What I want is to create a new array of the same size where the n-th column or row will be repeated:

```
col = 2 #third column of 'arr' will be repeated
array([[5 5 5 5]
       [9 9 9 9]
       [5 5 5 5]])

row = 0 #first row of 'arr' will be repeated
array([[4 8 5 9]
       [4 8 5 9]
       [4 8 5 9]])
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For the columns something like `np.broadcast_to(a[:,index,None], a.shape)` and should be similar for the rows

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!